# Running "bundle install" fails and asks me to run "bundle install"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, rvm, bundle

In fact, all gem-related commands result in the same error message, when run from inside the existing rails app I cloned from a git repo.

```
$ bundle install
Could not find tzinfo-0.3.27 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

$ gem list
Could not find tzinfo-0.3.27 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

$ bundle update
Could not find tzinfo-0.3.27 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

$ rails -v
Could not find tzinfo-0.3.27 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

---

I thought I already had rails installed... (following commands were run from outside the app directory):

```
$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.3

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.0.0]
```

Any idea what's up with "bundle install" telling me to run "bundle install"??

---

I exited my app directory and manually did

```
sudo gem install tzinfo -v 0.3.27
```

But upon entering my app directory again and trying "bundle install"...

```
$ bundle install
Could not find polyglot-0.3.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

So I went back out of the app directory, did

```
sudo gem install polyglot -v 0.3.1
```

"bundle install" now yielded

```
$ bundle install
Could not find treetop-1.4.9 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Why am I having to manually install all these random gems that I didn't have to in the past? (new dev env). Anyone know what I could have set up wrong in my environment?

Comment: What is in your Gemfile, does it contain `source 'http://rubygems.org'` ?

Comment: It contains source :rubygems, adding source 'http://rubygems.org' doesn't help, same errors.

Comment: Also... it turns out I can run `bundle install --gemfile=myApp/Gemfile` but it fails on another error (unrelated, I think). Why can't I run bundle install from within the app directory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK guess I fixed it..

For the gems that running `bundle install` complained about when run from inside the app directory, I installed them by going outside the app directory and doing `sudo gem install [gem]` one by one. Doing `bundle install --gemfile=myApp/Gemfile` also installed a couple of the missing gems.

I have no idea why I wasn't able to just run `bundle install` from inside the app directory...lame.

Comment: When you do 'gem install' it installs it globally to your ruby versions (assuming you're using Rbenv) so 'gem list' will show those. When you do bundle install, it installs gems for a particular project, in your project folder 'bundle show' will show gems for that project. When you have lots of projects, you don't want to pollute your global gems - they *should* (opinion, best practice) be installed on a per project basis.

Comment: try `bundle update` instead of `bundle install`. solved this issue for me

Comment: Agree with @ConnorLeech.  `bundle update` was the simple solution that worked for me as well.

Comment: I fixed this issue by running `$gem install bundler`. This will update (or install) your possibly outdated bundler. For a more detailed explanation check [this article](https://kolosek.com/rails-bundle-install-and-gemfile)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. Once I did:

`[root@smaug ~]# PATH=$PATH:~/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin`

`[root@smaug ~]# export PATH`

Then it was fixed and I could just

`[root@smaug msf3]# bundle install`

successfully.

Comment: For me, the problem was a configured `~/.gemrc` file. Good other place to look.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that all your commands have actually prepended `bundle exec`. If you take a look at the output it is bundler telling you your gems are not installed. This can happen if you have some plugin in rbenv installed like rbenv-bundle-exec, rbenv-bundler or rbenv-binstubs.
At least for me, it was happening the first time you try to `bundle install` in a project, because it actually detects there is a `Gemfile`in the current folder and tries to do `bundle exec bundle install` which obviously won't work.

You can use the solution of Tim, and run bundle install from outside the project folder.

You can disable or uninstall temporally the extension that is prepending `bundle exec` to ruby commands.

Or if the problem is happening because you use rbenv-bundle-exec, just do:

`NO_BUNDLE_EXEC=1 bundle install`

Comment: `NO_BUNDLE_EXEC=1 bundle install`  worked for me - was driving me nuts. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Installing ruby from [rubyinstaller](https://rubyinstaller.org/)

and then `gem install bundle` fixed the issue for me on a win 10 PC.

Answer (score 0):

`bundle exec bash` will have the same effect

Make sure `BUNDLER_ORIG_*` environment variables are not set.

If they are, it indicates you are in a `bundle exec` sub process.

Answer (score -3):

I had a very similar issue, after trying many different things I finally found a simple solution that worked...I restarted my computer (mac os 10.9x). No joke.