# Failure to bundle install on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I run into this error while trying to run bundle install.

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.8.1), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.

Could someone help me plse? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this issues is similar to the one discussed in the following link:
[Running "bundle install" fails and asks me to run "bundle install"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971290/running-bundle-install-fails-and-asks-me-to-run-bundle-install)